# Specialize template template parameter in a template function

Tags: templates, visual-c++

How could I specialize the template template parameter below :

```c
template< template<typename ElementType> class Container >
bool IsContainer() { return false; }
```

To like this( you might understand what I mean, the code below can't work) :

```c
template< std::Vector<int> >
bool IsContainer() { return true; }
```

Best regard.
Chen Lung Chin.

Comment: A *template template-parameter* is a parameter of a template that *takes a template as an argument*. `std::vector` names a template, but `std::vector<int>` does not. The latter names an explicit specialization of a template, which is *just a type, but not a template*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drop the template template parameter:

```
template< class Container >
bool IsContainer() { return false; }

template<>
bool IsContainer< std::vector< int > > () { return true; }

...
std::cout << IsContainer< int >() << std::endl;
std::cout << IsContainer< std::vector< int > > () << std::endl;
...
```

Comment: Partial specialization of function templates isn't allowed in C++11 either o.O (C++11 allows default arguments for function template parameters, for example)

Comment: Right. Too bad they decided not to insert partial specialization of function templates at least in C++11 :-(

Comment: I think it was a deliberate decision. Explicit specialization of function templates is already messy, because there's still overload resolution which comes before selecting the specialization.